# Find the largest exponent

Tags: exponentiation, gre-exam

I've got this GRE math question: The integer y is positive. If $6^y$ is a factor of $(2^{14})(3^{24})$, then what is the greatest possible value of y?

The answer is `14`. Why? I've been away from math too long so the answer doesn't compute in my brain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our expression $2^{14}\cdot 3^{24}$ can be rewritten as:
$$2\cdot 3\cdot 2^{13}\cdot 3^{23}$$
$$6\cdot 2^{13}\cdot 3^{23}$$
To make another $6$ factor, we just borrow a $2$ and a $3$ like this:
$$6^2\cdot 2^{12}\cdot 3^{22}$$
How many $6$s can we make? We can make as many $6$s as we want until either $2$ or $3$ runs out. In this case we can make as many $6$s as we want until $2$ runs out.
$$6^{14}\cdot 3^{10}$$
Therefore $y=14$

Comment: Never thought of it that way. Thanks for the clear answer, @JChau.

Answer (score 1):

$6$ requires one $2$ and one $3$. How many $2$ and $3$ can you club together maximum in your given number?